# Pivottable.js Pivot_UI how to Sort in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, pivot, pivottable.js

how to sort sum values in ascending or descending order using pivottabke.js, please give python example code thanks

```
                                    pivot_ui(struct_mto[[structConfig['MR Category'].iloc[0],structConfig['TotalUSD'].iloc[0],structConfig['Qty'].iloc[0],structConfig['WeightKg'].iloc[0],'MTO Revision']], rows=[structConfig['MR Category'].iloc[0]],rowOrder=["value_z_to_a"],cols=['MTO Revision'],outfile_path=chartFile,aggregatorName=["Sum","Decending"],vals=[structConfig['TotalUSD'].iloc[0]],rendererName="Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please give us more details.

Comment: i require the y axis USD total to be sorted either in ascending or decending order, how to i do that? i tried colOrder=["value_z_to_a"] didnt do anything...can you give example code for sort